# OpenID Connect - how to verify id token in Java?

Tags: java, openid, openid-connect

I've implemented the basic OpenID connect flow in my java application and it seems to work fine.

I'd like to use an existing java library to verify the id token, [as detailed here on a Salesforce page](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Inside_OpenID_Connect_on_Force.com#ID_Tokens) about implementing OpenId connect.

Are there any existing libraries that implement this well? I've got the response parsed, I just need to find some simple way to verify the id token is valid.

Comment: Have you seen this before: [Validating an ID token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login?hl=ja#validatinganidtoken)? They even have sample Java code to go along with the example.

Comment: Hmmm! Looks good - I'll try it out tomorrow and see how it goes.... Hopefully it's not too bound to Google+! Thanks!

Comment: For salesforce, a doc detailing how they manage verifying things is  here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_using_id_token.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following example will validate an `id_token` from an OAuth2 call for Salesforce, without any 3rd party libraries. Note that you'll have to supply a valid `id_token` below to test this out.

```
package jwt_validate_signature_sf_no_third_party;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Main
{
    // Sample id_token that needs validation. This is probably the only field you need to change to test your id_token.
    // If it doesn't work, try making sure the MODULUS and EXPONENT constants are what you're using, as detailed below.
    public static final String id_token = "YOUR_ID_TOKEN_HERE";
    public static final String[] id_token_parts = id_token.split("\\.");

    // Constants that come from the keys your token was signed with.
    // Correct values can be found from using the "kid" value and looking up the "n (MODULUS)" and "e (EXPONENT)" fields
    // at the following url: https://login.salesforce.com/id/keys
    //     MAJOR NOTE: This url will work for 90% of your use cases, but for the other 10%
    //     you'll need to make sure you get the "kid" value from the instance url that 
    //     the api responses from Salesforce suggest for your token, as the kid values *will* be different.
    //     e.g. Some users would need to get their kid values from https://na44.salesforce.com/id/keys for example.
    // The following 2 values are hard coded to work with the "kid=196" key values.
    public static final String MODULUS = "5SGw1jcqyFYEZaf39RoxAhlq-hfRSOsneVtsT2k09yEQhwB2myvf3ckVAwFyBF6y0Hr1psvu1FlPzKQ9YfcQkfge4e7eeQ7uaez9mMQ8RpyAFZprq1iFCix4XQw-jKW47LAevr9w1ttZY932gFrGJ4gkf_uqutUny82vupVUETpQ6HDmIL958SxYb_-d436zi5LMlHnTxcR5TWIQGGxip-CrD7vOA3hrssYLhNGQdwVYtwI768EvwE8h4VJDgIrovoHPH1ofDQk8-oG20eEmZeWugI1K3z33fZJS-E_2p_OiDVr0EmgFMTvPTnQ75h_9vyF1qhzikJpN9P8KcEm8oGu7KJGIn8ggUY0ftqKG2KcWTaKiirFFYQ981PhLHryH18eOIxMpoh9pRXf2y7DfNTyid99ig0GUH-lzAlbKY0EV2sIuvEsIoo6G8YT2uI72xzl7sCcp41FS7oFwbUyHp_uHGiTZgN7g-18nm2TFmQ_wGB1xCwJMFzjIXq1PwEjmg3W5NBuMLSbG-aDwjeNrcD_4vfB6yg548GztQO2MpV_BuxtrZDJQm-xhJXdm4FfrJzWdwX_JN9qfsP0YU1_mxtSU_m6EKgmwFdE3Yh1WM0-kRRSk3gmNvXpiKeVduzm8I5_Jl7kwLgBw24QUVaLZn8jC2xWRk_jcBNFFLQgOf9U";
    public static final String EXPONENT = "AQAB";

    public static final String ID_TOKEN_HEADER = base64UrlDecode(id_token_parts[0]);
    public static final String ID_TOKEN_PAYLOAD = base64UrlDecode(id_token_parts[1]);
    public static final byte[] ID_TOKEN_SIGNATURE = base64UrlDecodeToBytes(id_token_parts[2]);

    public static String base64UrlDecode(String input)
    {
        byte[] decodedBytes = base64UrlDecodeToBytes(input);
        String result = new String(decodedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return result;
    }

    public static byte[] base64UrlDecodeToBytes(String input)
    {
        Base64 decoder = new Base64(-1, null, true);
        byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode(input);

        return decodedBytes;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        dumpJwtInfo();
        validateToken();
    }

    public static void dump(String data)
    {
        System.out.println(data);
    }

    public static void dumpJwtInfo()
    {
        dump(ID_TOKEN_HEADER);
        dump(ID_TOKEN_PAYLOAD);
    }

    public static void validateToken()
    {
        PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKey(MODULUS, EXPONENT);
        byte[] data = (id_token_parts[0] + "." + id_token_parts[1]).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        try
        {
            boolean isSignatureValid = verifyUsingPublicKey(data, ID_TOKEN_SIGNATURE, publicKey);
            System.out.println("isSignatureValid: " + isSignatureValid);
        }
        catch (GeneralSecurityException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String MODULUS, String EXPONENT)
    {
        byte[] nb = base64UrlDecodeToBytes(MODULUS);
        byte[] eb = base64UrlDecodeToBytes(EXPONENT);
        BigInteger n = new BigInteger(1, nb);
        BigInteger e = new BigInteger(1, eb);

        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(n, e);
        try
        {
            PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(rsaPublicKeySpec);

            return publicKey;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cant create public key", ex);
        }
    }

    private static boolean verifyUsingPublicKey(byte[] data, byte[] signature, PublicKey pubKey) throws GeneralSecurityException
    {
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initVerify(pubKey);
        sig.update(data);

        return sig.verify(signature);
    }
}
```

Note if you're not opposed to using a third party library, [I'd totally suggest using this](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/JWS%20Examples#markdown-header-jws-verification-using-a-jwk), as it works great. I couldn't use it for business reasons, but was glad to find it as it helped me understand how this process works, validated an `id_token`, I'm sure in a much more robust way.

Also, to be certain this request was signed by the same client, ensure the `aud` parameter in the payload matches your own client key given to you by Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

As part of [Spring Security OAuth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth), the Spring team has developed a library called [Spring Security JWT](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/spring-security-jwt) that allows manipulation of JWTs, including decoding and verifying tokens.

See the following helper class for example:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-jwt/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/jwt/JwtHelper.java

The library is in version 1.0.0-RELEASE and available in the maven repo.

Comment: Note that since, The Spring Security OAuth project is deprecated. See the link for details.