# Does Spring OAuth2 SSO support Azure Active Directory signing key rollover for token verification?

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I am developing a SSO application using Spring OAuth2 SSO. I am using Azure AD as OAuth2 Provider which has [signing key rollover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover) and exposes the public keys with JWKS URI (OpenID configuration) as shown below. Is there any way I can do token validation in Spring OAuth2 SSO?

```
{
  "keys": [
{
  "kty": "RSA",
  "use": "sig",
  "kid": "9FXDpbfMFT2SvQuXh846YTwEIBw",
  "x5t": "9FXDpbfMFT2SvQuXh846YTwEIBw",
  "n": "kvt1VmR4nwkNM8jMU0wmj2gSS8NznbOt2pZI6Z7HQT_esF7W19GZR7Y72Xo1i5zXRDM9o3GeTIjBrnr3yy41Q_EaUQ7C-b-Hmg94Vy7EBZyBhi_mznz0dYWs2MIXwR86Nni9TmgTXvjgTPF2YGJoZt4TwcMFefW8rijCVyNrCBA0XspDouNJavvG0BEMXYigoThFjLRXS5U3h4BDfNZFZZS3dyliNOXfgRn2k7oITz8h_ueiPvmDRFh38AeQgx1cELhKWc3P5ugtttraSwgH7nP2NUguO9nCrHuL6TZ-KWpmRWZqwH-jYKFQVt3CDpzwNM6XJL-oHbl1x-gI3YYX5w",
  "e": "AQAB",
  "x5c": [
    "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"
  ]
},
{
  "kty": "RSA",
  "use": "sig",
  "kid": "VWVIc1WD1Tksbb301sasM5kOq5Q",
  "x5t": "VWVIc1WD1Tksbb301sasM5kOq5Q",
  "n": "wxZQBChCrsCnhy-U6jWszJNnpSwYM3nmF7iwBkp0Qa57Wz7XQLnhUucZe_YkEJg6hJg16XAbZ_3oZnwLqQVlArfu5ldP9IdgOgPJYFGZXamE0v3BFtf1K2leiHqfmt06zJ2NhHCQ5p2yRzrrMV23kjK5bz8a_gQsdkIkBW7qE9TbJFU5D3zPk-sbJi7SIOLx5XRI6eFwu4z1IGooBbNiRopDEdcQizJqH_7PQJuBBk-a-ntI05mZaEZ2nbo8DDu046TEkqA2IRJ1FIvvdxrAi5NQ6E6YcYulNWxUaxBD2e42f9jmhBTBYknN23p3QEmRWvhgFRyDoK-M5XFw1H0mbw",
  "e": "AQAB",
  "x5c": [
    "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"
  ]
},
{
  "kty": "RSA",
  "use": "sig",
  "kid": "2S4SCVGs8Sg9LS6AqLIq6DpW-g8",
  "x5t": "2S4SCVGs8Sg9LS6AqLIq6DpW-g8",
  "n": "oZ-QQrNuB4ei9ATYrT61ebPtvwwYWnsrTpp4ISSp6niZYb92XM0oUTNgqd_C1vGN8J-y9wCbaJWkpBf46CjdZehrqczPhzhHau8WcRXocSB1u_tuZhv1ooAZ4bAcy79UkeLiG60HkuTNJJC8CfaTp1R97szBhuk0Vz5yt4r5SpfewIlBCnZUYwkDS172H9WapQu-3P2Qjh0l-JLyCkdrhvizZUk0atq5_AIDKRU-A0pRGc-EZhUL0LqUMz6c6M2s_4GnQaScv44A5iZUDD15B6e8Apb2yARohkWmOnmRcTVfes8EkfxjzZEzm3cNkvP0ogILyISHKlkzy2OmlU6iXw",
  "e": "AQAB",
  "x5c": [
    "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"
  ]
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description, you were implementing the OAuth 2.0 Provider using Azure AD with Spring Security OAuth.

Based on my understanding, the provider role in OAuth 2.0 is actually split between Authorization Service and Resource Service. There is no need to validate the token if you only get the token in your app and send the token to the resource which protected by Azure AD. For example, your web app implement OAuth 2.0 Provider to enable users get the access token from Azure AD for the Microsoft Graph, then you web app can call the Microsoft Graph using this access token. And the Microsoft Graph will verify the access token.

If you also implement the resource service and protect it with Azure AD via Spring Security OAuth, you need to implement `ResourceServerTokenServices` to verify the token and handle the key rollover.

You can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875253/openid-connect-how-to-verify-id-token-in-java) for verifying the access token manually. And more detail about Spring Oauth2 development, you can refer the link below:

[OAuth 2 Developers Guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)